# SQL query on the where clause

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

```
SELECT `p_id`, `pnmnia`, `organism`, `antib_1`, `antib_2`, `antib_3`, `antib_4`, `antib_5` 
FROM `treatment` 
WHERE `case_id` = `AP00103`
```

this is my query. i m getting an error displaying "#1054 - Champ 'AP00103' inconnu dans where clause "

what does this imply?

Comment: Put quotes `"` around "AP00103". If you omit the quotes, PhpMyAdmin looks for a column called (not containing) AP00103.

Comment: What is the data type of `case_id` column?

Comment: data type is varchar